# Can you explain by giving a simple example of how to calculate inter-rater reliability with two raters and multiple nominal categories for each item?

Tags: agreement-statistics

I have a data set with  45 responses for an open ended question from a survey. The two raters classified each of the response into 7 nominal categories. Each rater was allowed to select more than one category to classify each response. That is rater 1 can say a response can fit into category 1 as well as category 7.
Can you explain me with a simple example as how to calculate the inter rater reliability. I have read your posts regarding the same question and have also tried to understand the article "Extension of the kappa coefficient" by krammer.
It will be really helpful if you can explain this using a simple example.
thanks in advance